# Moving Background and be able to drag

Tags: javascript

I am working on something similar to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/uMk7m/2/

using this code

```
const bg = document.querySelector('.box');
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth / 55;
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight / 55;

bg.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const mouseX = e.clientX / windowWidth;
  const mouseY = e.clientY / windowHeight;


  bg.style.transform = `translate3d(-${mouseX}%, -${mouseY}%, 0)`;
  buildcanvas();
});
```

Background image moves when mouse cursor moves over the image. Works just fine as this code should.

But I am using a very large image as a background and want the user to have the option to drag the image till the end.

I tried this code

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');

if (container) {
  Draggable.create(".box", {
    bounds: container
  });
}

document.querySelector('.item').addEventListener('click', e => {
  alert('Klikkasit');
})
```

But what happens is when I drag image and move mouse, the image comes back to the original position.

How do it fix this?